# Using nohup on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, ksh, sftp, nohup

I need to transfer a large number of files over SFTP (only between Solaris servers) which takes a very long time. I cannot keep my PC on for this duration. I tried:

```
nohup sftp server1
```

While the shell is open, I see files are downloaded. When I close the shell it stops. In `ps -ef` I don't see the `sftp` process. The file nohup.out states: Killed by signal 15

If instead I do <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd>, `bg`, `disown` it works. However this requires the bash shell; how can I do this in ksh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SFTP as normal
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>
3. `nohup -ga $(pgrep sftp)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do Ctrl+Z, `bg`, `disown` in ksh as well. You'd want that in addition to `nohup`, i.e.,

```
nohup sftp server1
...
<Ctrl+Z>
bg
disown
```

However my recommendation here would be to use [**screen**](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). In OpenSolaris, it's in the `SUNWscreen` package. Run `screen`, which starts a shell in a new virtual terminal. Run `sftp server` inside that shell (you can also directly run `screen sftp server`). Initiate your transfer, then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to disconnect (“detach”) from the screen session. The processes inside the session will keep running. Later, you can reattach to that screen session with `screen -rd`.

Comment: hi gilles.  disown does not work in ksh.  here's the error i get:  ksh: disown:  not found.  that said, i agree with the use of screen.  however i don't have root access to this particular server so i won't be able to install GNU screen.

Comment: @anurag: Oh, `disown` is in OpenSolaris, I didn't think it was a new feature. You should be able to just drop a `screen` executable or compile it from source and put it in your account — at least on OpenSolaris screen doesn't need any extra permission. Failing that you could install a `bash` executable in your account.

Answer (score 1):

if you in ksh under Solaris following is just a single step for all:

% nohup command > command.log 2>&1 &

it is ok if you exit then your ksh terminal.